# client issues with iPad browser closing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ipad

A client of ours is attempting to purchase items on one of our stores. Unfortunately I cannot disclose a link to said store because its behind a login wall for their company.

The store is made with C#/asp.net. Every time this person gets to a specific point in the checkout process, his browser is immediately closed and reopened to his homepage.

I realize that given the tiny amount of information, a definite answer is not possible but I am at a complete loss here.

Does anyone know what would be remotely capable of causing this?

If anyone wants to know specifics I can look up code from the site and let you know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some pointers on how to proceed:

- Is it reproducible on other iPads?
- Is it reproducible on the same iPad with a different browser like Opera Mini?
- Is it reproducible on an iPhone with Safari?
- Is it reproducible on a Mac with Safari?

Comment: I'll look into some of these.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the browser is on the iPad??? its hard to say.  I'm assuming from your description that it is possible to access the site from the web/intranet as well.

Does the site work normally in other browsers like ie or ff?

The login process (depending on how it is designed) sounds like one that either uses windows auth connected to an ldap or possibly windows forms?

If that is the case is there a possibility that the authentication cookie could be timing out/destroyed and redirecting the user back to log in?

Does the log in screen have a logout query string?

Comment: It works like a charm on my laptop. Windows 7 with IE8,9, Firefox 3, Chrome, and Safari. I went through with him on the phone and from login to the browser restarting was about 4 minutes. The set timeout on the backend is 15 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: are there any situations where you know that it works in other iPads?  Are you doing any sort of client side coding? and what is the browser that the user is using on their iPad?

Comment: I have an iPad here that was loaned to me through my IT admin. I can place orders like normal. The most confusing part is the client was given a new iPad from the Apple Store and it still happens.

Comment: @castis: Try to give *your* iPad - with which it works - to the client and see whether it works with him or not. If it doesn't, he might do something else than you do or the data that is received by the iPad is somehow "changed" through their IT infrastructure...

Comment: I would love to do that except he's located in another state. I'll see if I can find someone else in his location that has an iPad and have him try it there.